# Problems with blinking my table rows .

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which has a table where I have to blink some rows in a determined condition .

This page is a partial view , and I load it with setTimeInterval function .

The problem is , after loading the page for several times , the blink function becomes crazy , like the interval time has changed .

below is the code where I use the blink page .

```
    $('#tblSolicitacao').find('tr').each(function () {
        var status = $.trim($(this).find('#solicitante-status').text());
        switch (status) {
            case "Solicitado":
                $(this).addClass('solicitacao');
                var on = false;
                setInterval(function blink() {
                    on = !on;
                    if (on) {
                        $('.solicitacao').addClass('solicitacao-blink');
                        $('.solicitacao').css("color", "white");
                    } else {
                        $('.solicitacao').css("color", "black");
                        $('.solicitacao-blink').removeClass('solicitacao-blink');

                    }
                    return blink;
                }(), 1000);
                break;
```

.
 .
 .

it's inside a switch clause , to check the status of the row .

and below I have the main page which calls the partial view .

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    loadPagina();

    window.setInterval("loadPagina()", 10000);
});
```

I really need help with this and if you guys need any other explanation , pls don't hesitate on asking me .

Tks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var BlinkerOn = true;    
$(function(){

  //find the things you want to blink
  $('#tblSolicitacao').find('tr').each(function () {
      var status = $.trim($(this).find('#solicitante-status').text());
      switch (status) {
        case "Solicitado":
            $(this).addClass('solicitacao');
            break;
    };
  });


  //add a single interval
  setInterval(function()
  {
    if(BlinkerOn) {
      $(".solicitacao").addClass("classWithCSSyouWant");
    }
    else {
      $(".solicitacao").removeClass("classWithCSSyouWant");
    }
    BlinkerOn = !BlinkerOn;

  },1000);

});
```

Comment: I tried that before , using a global variable , but it doesn't seem to work in my case . the blink function still crazy using in that way . But thanks for your answer !

Comment: @ruynunes have you tried making a simple version in jsfiddle? Then we could modify it and show you what's going wrong?

Comment: Charlie , I thought that the solution from shadow wizard worked . But in several minutes the setInterval becomes crazy , as I told before . To put this in a jsFiddle isn't going to be easy , because I have an ajax call to load some information from the server . The function loadPagina() is the ajax call . And as you told , the problem could be the the many setInterval calls inside this switch clause . In your edit , how I will call a single setInterval , knowing that I should call it for each row ? Any idea ?

Comment: $(".solicitacao").removeClass("myClass"); will remove myClass from every html element with the class solicitacao.  You don't need to have it "call each row" that part is done automatically

Comment: Undertstood ! I'm testing here what you said . At my first test, I understood the many instances that I was invoking for the variable which is the callback for setInterval . I changed here and now the reference is the same for each row . Just checking if it'll work ! But it seems that now is correct ! I'll give a reply here when I finish this test .

Comment: Hey Charlie ! it worked !!! I had to clearInterval everytime that I load the page via Ajax , to remove the previous allocation of setInterval . I got it working using all this .

Answer (score 0):

You are setting more and more intervals.

Either start only one single interval, or simply clear the previous interval before starting new one:

```
var blinkInterval = 0
//...
$(this).addClass('solicitacao');
var on = false;
clearInterval(blinkInterval);
blinkInterval = setInterval(function blink() {
    on = !on;
    //...
}(), 1000);
```

Another option is using `setTimeout()` instead, which executes only once.

Comment: Shadow Wizard , I have another setTimeInterval to fire a notification to inform the user about new solicitations , in my case , about new "Solicitacoes" . Could it be a problem ?

Comment: Might be other problem, but like I said, adding more and more intervals are most likely the cause for the "becomes crazy" you describe.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply . I'm refactoring my code here , to remove all those SetTimeInterval from my code . But is there a way to use many SetTimeInterval inside a page ?

Comment: No there isn't a generic way, just have proper logic and clean code and it should work fine.